# \SubMatrix from nicematrix does not work with eqmakebox

Tags: nicematrix

I am trying to align the brackets in the following table. Usually I use `\eqmakebox` to get the results as I want. However, when trying to align the contents inside `NiceTabularX`, I get an error message

> File ended while scanning use of __nicematrix_CodeAfter_i:n.

[image]

In the following MWE, when removing `\eqmakebox[equalized][r]`, the code works well

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][l]{\eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle\color{black}#3$}}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    
    \begin{description}
            
            \item[Summary of Conversion of Quantities Across Gears]
            
    \end{description}
    
    \renewcommand{\bigstrutjot}{5mm}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}
    \newlength{\widthWord}
    \setlength{\widthWord}{\widthof{Displacement}}
    
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}m[c]{\widthWord} X[3,c, m] X[1, c, m]}
            
            Quantity & Conversion Rule & Notes
            \\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
            \addlinespace[1.2mm]
            
            Torque & \adjustbox{valign=b}{\eqmakebox[equalized][r]{${T_{\mathrm{new}} = T_{\mathrm{old}}}$}
                        $\left[ \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}} \right]\phantom{^{2}}$
                    } & Torque increases with teeth in gears
            \\
            \addlinespace
            
            \Block[c]{1-1}{Mechanical \\ Impedance} & \adjustbox{valign=b}{\eqmakebox[equalized][r]{$Z_{\mathrm{M, \thinspace new} = Z_{\mathrm{M, \thinspace old}}}$}
                    $\left[ \bigstrut
                    \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}} \right]^{2}$
                    } & Mechanical impedance increases with teeth in gears
            \\
            \addlinespace
            
            \Block[c]{1-1}{Angular \\ Displacement} & \adjustbox{valign=b}{\eqmakebox[equalized][r]{$\theta_{\mathrm{new}} =  \theta_{\mathrm{old}}$}
                    $\left[ \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}} \right]\phantom{^{2}}$
                    } & Angular displacement decreases with teeth in gears
            \\
            
            \CodeAfter
            \SubMatrix.{2-1}{2-1}\}[xshift=1mm]
            \SubMatrix.{3-1}{3-1}\}[xshift=1mm]
            \SubMatrix.{4-1}{4-1}\}[xshift=1mm]
            
        \end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. I reformatted the code for readability and removed causes for errors due to blank lines.

I also propose a simpler version.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][l]{\eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle\color{black}#3$}}
\newlength{\widthWord}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    
\begin{description}
  \item[Summary of Conversion of Quantities Across Gears]
\end{description}
    
\renewcommand{\bigstrutjot}{5mm}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength{\widthWord}{\widthof{Displacement}}
    
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}m[c]{\widthWord} X[3,c, m] X[1, c, m]}
            
Quantity & Conversion Rule & Notes \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\addlinespace[1.2mm]
            
Torque &
  \adjustbox{valign=b}{%
    \eqmakebox[equalized][r]{${T_{\mathrm{new}} = T_{\mathrm{old}}}$}
    $\left[ 
      \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}
           {\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}
    \right]\phantom{^{2}}$%
  } &
  Torque increases with teeth in gears
\\
\addlinespace
            
\Block[c]{1-1}{Mechanical \\ Impedance} &
  \adjustbox{valign=b}{%
    \eqmakebox[equalized][r]{$Z_{\mathrm{M, \thinspace new} = Z_{\mathrm{M, \thinspace old}}}$}
    $\left[ \bigstrut
      \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}
           {\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}
    \right]^{2}$%
  } &
  Mechanical impedance increases with teeth in gears
\\
\addlinespace
            
\Block[c]{1-1}{Angular \\ Displacement} &
  \adjustbox{valign=b}{%
    \eqmakebox[equalized][r]{$\theta_{\mathrm{new}} =  \theta_{\mathrm{old}}$}
    $\left[
      \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}
           {\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}
    \right]\phantom{^{2}}$%
  } &
  Angular displacement decreases with teeth in gears
\\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix.{2-1}{2-1}\}[xshift=1mm]
  \SubMatrix.{3-1}{3-1}\}[xshift=1mm]
  \SubMatrix.{4-1}{4-1}\}[xshift=1mm]
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{frame}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    
\begin{description}
  \item[Summary of Conversion of Quantities Across Gears]
\end{description}

\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{\bfseries}c
  >{$\displaystyle}r<{$}
  @{\enspace}
  >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}
  c
  @{}
}
Quantity & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Conversion Rule} & Notes \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\addlinespace[1.2mm]
            
Torque &
T_{\mathrm{new}} = T_{\mathrm{old}} &
\left[ 
  \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}
       {\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}
\right] &
\splitcell{Torque \\ increases with \\ teeth in gears}
\\
\addlinespace

\splitcell{Mechanical \\ Impedance} &
Z_{\mathrm{M, \thinspace new}} = Z_{\mathrm{M, \thinspace old}} &
\left[ \bigstrut
  \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}
       {\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}
\right]^{2} &
\splitcell{Mechanical \\ impedance \\ increases with \\ teeth in gears}
\\
\addlinespace

\splitcell{Angular \\ Displacement} &
\theta_{\mathrm{new}} =  \theta_{\mathrm{old}} &
\left[
  \frac{\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Source} Shaft}}
       {\stackanchor{Number of Teeth of Gear}{in the \alert{Destination} Shaft}}
\right] &
\splitcell{Angular \\ displacement \\ decreases with \\ teeth in gears}
\\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix.{2-1}{2-1}\}[xshift=-2mm]
  \SubMatrix.{3-1}{3-1}\}[xshift=-2mm]
  \SubMatrix.{4-1}{4-1}\}[xshift=-2mm]
\end{NiceTabular*}
    
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]